# Flutter/Dart socket communication, characters encoding issue

Tags: sockets, flutter, dart, encoding

For a proof of concept where 2 applications, written in Flutter and running on the same device, need to exchange information, I am using the 'dart:io' Sockets.

One of the 2 applications implements a SocketServer to receive the information and the other initializes the sockets communication.

From a connection perspective, this is working fine, using the following code:

Code of the server:

```
ServerSocket.bind('127.0.0.1', 8080).then((ServerSocket socketServer) {
    socketServer.listen((Socket socket) {
       socket.listen((List<int> data){
          String result = String.fromCharCodes(data);
          print('received: $result'); 
        });
    });
}).catchError(print);
```

Code of the client:

```
Socket.connect('127.0.0.1', 8080).then((socket) {
   String data = 'Les élèves regardent par la fenêtre';
   socket.write(data);
   print("sent: $data");
}).catchError(print);
```

However, when I try to send a String which contains accentuated characters, I have the following outcome:

```
sent: Les élèves regardent par la fenêtre
received: Les Ã©lÃ¨ves regardent par la fenÃªtre
```

This looks like an encoding related issue but I haven't yet been able to solve it.

Would anybody have any idea how to proceed to have this working?
Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using the [Encoding class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/Encoding-class.html)?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution.
Here it is:

Code for the Client:

```
Socket.connect('127.0.0.1', 8080).then((socket) {
   String data = 'Les élèves regardent par la fenêtre';

   socket.encoding = utf8;   // <== force the encoding
   socket.write(data);
   print("sent: $data");
}).catchError(print);
```

Code for the Server:

```
ServerSocket.bind('127.0.0.1', 8080).then((ServerSocket socketServer) {
    socketServer.listen((Socket socket) {
       socket.listen((List<int> data){
          String result = utf8.decode(data);
          print('received: $result'); 
        });
    });
}).catchError(print);
```

The solution consists of "forcing" the encoding to utf8

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using `ut8.encode` when writing the data, and `utf8.decode` when reading it on the other side.